# Do std::promise::set_value() and std::future::wait() provide a memory fence?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

If I do the following:

```
std::promise<void> p;
int a = 1;

std::thread t([&] {
  a = 2;
  p.set_value();
});

p.get_future().wait();

// Is the value of `a` guaranteed to be 2 here?
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value) has this to say about `set_value()`, but I am not sure what it means:

> Calls to this function do not introduce data races with calls to get_future (but they need not synchronize with each other).

Do `set_value()` and `wait()` provide an acquire/release synchronization (or some other form)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my reading I believe `a` is guarnteed to be 2 at the end. Notice the information about the [promise itself](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) (emphasis mine):

> The promise is the "push" end of the promise-future communication channel: **the operation that stores a value in the shared state synchronizes-with (as defined in std::memory_order) the successful return from any function that is waiting on the shared state (such as std::future::get).** Concurrent access to the same shared state may conflict otherwise: for example multiple callers of std::shared_future::get must either all be read-only or provide external synchronization.

Of course I encourage you to read what it means that something synchronizes-with. For this situation it means that `set_value` is seen as inter-thread happening-before and therefore from what I get writing `a` is a visible side effect. You can find more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

What does mean your qoute about `get_future`? It means simply that you can safely call `get_future` and `set_value` from different threads and it won't break anything. But also it does not necessarily introduce any memory fences by itself. The only synchronization points that are sure and safe are `set_value` from `std::promise` and `get` from `std::future`.