# Is c++ std::future::wait() always cache-safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is c++ std::future<>.wait() always cache-safe?

```
int x = 0;
std::future<void> fut = std::async( std::launch::async,
                                    [&]() { x = 1; } );

fut.wait();
std::cout << x;
```

In VS2019, wait() is implemented using a mutex. Therefore, the above snipped should be cache-safe. Am I right?

How is it on other platforms?

Maybe the same question, but not identically:
[Do std::promise::set_value() and std::future::wait() provide a memory fence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509913/do-stdpromiseset-value-and-stdfuturewait-provide-a-memory-fence)

Comment: What is "cache-safe"? Do you mean to ask if it is synchronized or thread-safe, as in it prevents race conditions?

Comment: Yes, is x always synchronized?

Comment: Yes, `wait()` blocks until the value is available which happens after the async function returns. So anything after `wait()` is sequenced after the async function completes.

Comment: If the duplicate question you included in your question does not answer your question, please elaborate on why they are different and this question can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! In the linked question, there was no direct use of future (a thread was started manually, but futures can be implemented without the use of threads). But the mechanism should be the same.